# Javascript string parser - escape issue

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing

I'm running a Node server that receives a plain utf8 text and parses the content to JSON. Part of the JSON will be the body of an HTML document.

The problem is that when the input has characters such as "**ä**" or " **'** ", the HTML document gets all crazy. I guess it has to do with the coding/decoding of the parser for these special characters.

Any ideas regarding this ?

[EDIT]

The parsing and JSON object are basically this:

```
var string = <mail_body><html> html code here...<html><mail_body>

var mail_body = string.split("<mail_body>")[1]
var obj = {
  "subject": "subject 123",
  "mail_body": mail_body
}
```

Comment: Do you control the incoming text?

Comment: Depends on what control means. I receive the text as a stream: stream.on('data', function(chunk) {buffer = buffer+chunk.toString('utf8')}). But the data itself comes from other source, so I can't trim out the characters I don't want to include

Comment: Do you have any way of telling what the boundaries of the HTML are going to be? What might be really helpful here would be an example of the format the input is likely to be in. If it's a mix of json and html it will be more tricky than if it is plain html, for example.

Comment: glenatron, just edited the post showing the way I'm parsing the content and construction the JSON object

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for the "'"

```
var escapedText = text.replace(/\\'/g, "\\'");
```

and use a unicode for the "letter a with eyes"

like this -> \u2665

https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes

Comment: Thanks. Since I do not control the input content, do you know any way for applying the replace to all characters that have the same output ? I'm using Node.js, so I guess a module would do the work, but I couldn't find anything so far.

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing you need to do is to escape the incoming string to eliminate quotes that will break your JSON, which is the only significant problem I would expect to see with Node - [browsers have a slightly harder time](http://www.thorntech.com/2012/07/4-things-you-must-do-when-putting-html-in-json/). From your input you're looking at something like this:

```
   var string = <mail_body><html> html code here...<html><mail_body> 
   var mail_body = string.split("<mail_body>")[1]
   mail_body = mail_body.replace(/\"/g, '\\"'); // regex for global replace, have to escape quotes
```

That should get you a mail body that doesn't unexpectedly end and break the rest of your JSON.